# Insert a comma on multi line textfield flutter

Tags: flutter

I need to add a comma after the user presses the enter key on the keyboard. I'm using a multi-line text field.

This is my code:

```
TextField(
            textCapitalization: TextCapitalization.words,
            textInputAction: TextInputAction.newline,
            controller: ExpressTextController,
            autofocus: true,
            maxLines: 10,
            decoration: InputDecoration(
                     hintStyle: TextStyle(color: Colors.grey[400], fontSize: 15)),
            style: TextStyle(
              fontSize: 18,
            ),
            keyboardType: TextInputType.multiline,
          ),
```

Answer (score 0, accepted):

You would need to edit the text of the controller in the onchanged. Not sure if this is the best approach but this is the first thing that comes to mind.

```
onChanged: (val) {
  RegExp regex = new RegExp(r"\n+|,+\n+"); // 1
  if (regex.hasMatch(val)) { // 2
    final newVal = val.replaceAll(regex, ",\n"); // 3
    ExpressTextController.text = newVal; // 4
    ExpressTextController.selection = TextSelection.fromPosition(
      TextPosition(offset: ExpressTextController.text.length)); // 5
  }
},
```

1. create a regex that finds all line breaks or commas followed by a line break
2. check for the linebreak
3. if there is a line break then add a comma before the linebreak
4. set the new value of the controller
5. set the position of the cursor to be at the end after we assign the new value to the controller. If we don't do this the cursor will get assigned to the start after every comma

Comment: is there any way to make multiple lines using this code?

Comment: Updated the code. This will overwrite any 2 back to back commas followed by a line break

Comment: If this solved your problem could you please mark it as the correct answer ?

Answer (score 0):

You can do that using `TextInputFormatter`. In your `TextField`, set its `inputFormatters` property.

```
TextField(
  ...
  inputFormatters: [CommaNewLineInputFormatter()],
),
```

Here's a sample formatter for your scenario.

```
class CommaNewLineInputFormatter extends TextInputFormatter {
  final StringBuffer _newText = StringBuffer();
  final List<int> _separatorCodeUnits = '\n,'.codeUnits;

  bool _useOldValueNext = false;

  int get _newLineCodeUnit => _separatorCodeUnits.first;

  int get _commaCodeUnit => _separatorCodeUnits.last;

  @override
  TextEditingValue formatEditUpdate(
    TextEditingValue oldValue,
    TextEditingValue newValue,
  ) {
    if (_useOldValueNext) {
      _useOldValueNext = false;
      return oldValue;
    }

    final int selectionIdx = newValue.selection.baseOffset - 1;
    final int selectionCodeUnit = newValue.text.codeUnitAt(selectionIdx);

    if (newValue.text.length < oldValue.text.length) {
      int minusSelectionOffset = 0;
      _newText.clear();

      if (selectionCodeUnit == _newLineCodeUnit) {
        _newText.write(newValue.text);
        _useOldValueNext = true;
      } else if (selectionCodeUnit == _commaCodeUnit) {
        _newText.writeAll([
          newValue.text.substring(0, selectionIdx),
          newValue.text.substring(selectionIdx + 1),
        ]);
        minusSelectionOffset = 1;
        _useOldValueNext = true;
      } else {
        return newValue;
      }

      return newValue.copyWith(
        text: _newText.toString(),
        selection: newValue.selection.copyWith(
          baseOffset: newValue.selection.baseOffset - minusSelectionOffset,
          extentOffset: newValue.selection.extentOffset - minusSelectionOffset,
        ),
      );
    } else if (selectionCodeUnit == _newLineCodeUnit ||
        selectionCodeUnit == _commaCodeUnit) {
      final int prevCharCodeUnit = newValue.text.codeUnitAt(selectionIdx - 1);
      final bool isPrevCharSeparator = prevCharCodeUnit == _newLineCodeUnit ||
          prevCharCodeUnit == _commaCodeUnit;
      int addSelectionOffset = 1;

      if (selectionCodeUnit == _newLineCodeUnit &&
          prevCharCodeUnit == _newLineCodeUnit) {
        // Do not move cursor if previous and new character is a new line
        // because the new character won't be added.
        addSelectionOffset = -1;
      } else if (isPrevCharSeparator) {
        // Move cursor by 1 if "," is typed after a "," in the TextField.
        addSelectionOffset = 0;
      }

      _newText.clear();
      _newText.writeAll([
        newValue.text.substring(0, selectionIdx),
        if (!isPrevCharSeparator) ',\n',
        newValue.text.substring(selectionIdx + 1),
      ]);

      return newValue.copyWith(
        text: _newText.toString(),
        selection: newValue.selection.copyWith(
          baseOffset: newValue.selection.baseOffset + addSelectionOffset,
          extentOffset: newValue.selection.extentOffset + addSelectionOffset,
        ),
      );
    }

    return newValue;
  }
}
```

Answer (score 0):

The effective way to solve this is using regex (*general advanced logical statements, not specific to any language like dart or java*). Visit [this site](https://www.regextester.com/) to know more about cheat codes and some general examples of regex.

I wanted to add some more features to the question:

1. Enter to line along with comma when the comma was pressed and vice versa, when enter was pressed a comma should appear before entering to a new line
2. Remove unnecessary spaces at starting and ending of each line (at ends)
3. Don't allow the user to leave an empty line (no consecutive commas or newlines)
4. Format the copy-pasted content, which is not typed (when double commas or any other things require formatting) [*minor issues might exist with below code**]
5. Most importantly text controller should not reach the endpoint when a user types a letter other than a comma or newline (this allows the user to modify the value in the previous lines)

Especially because of point 5, it is a good practice to use multiple simple regex statements. In the text field, (add max lines to check them properly and) add the below "on changed" code

```
              onChanged: (val) {
                RegExp comma = new RegExp(r"(?!,\n),+|,\n,");
                if (comma.hasMatch(val)) {
                  final newVal = val.replaceAll(comma, ",\n");
                  _roomIdController.text = newVal;
                  _roomIdController.selection = TextSelection.fromPosition(
                      TextPosition(offset: _roomIdController.text.length));
                }
                RegExp enter = new RegExp(r"(?<!,)\n+"); //|\n,\n
                if (enter.hasMatch(val)) {
                  final newVal = val.replaceAll(enter, ",\n");
                  _roomIdController.text = newVal;
                  _roomIdController.selection = TextSelection.fromPosition(
                      TextPosition(offset: _roomIdController.text.length));
                }
                RegExp double1 = new RegExp(r",{2,}\n*|,*\n{2,}");
                if (double1.hasMatch(val)) {
                  final newVal = val.replaceAll(double1, ",\n");
                  _roomIdController.text = newVal;
                  _roomIdController.selection = TextSelection.fromPosition(
                      TextPosition(offset: _roomIdController.text.length));
                }
                RegExp trimEnds =
                    new RegExp(r"\s+,\s*\n\s*|\s*,\s+\n\s*|\s*,\s*\n\s+");
                if (trimEnds.hasMatch(val)) {
                  final newVal = val.replaceAll(trimEnds, ",\n");
                  _roomIdController.text = newVal;
                  _roomIdController.selection = TextSelection.fromPosition(
                      TextPosition(offset: _roomIdController.text.length));
                }
                RegExp trim =
                    new RegExp(r"\s{2,}\b|\b\s{2,}"); //word boundary \b
                if (trim.hasMatch(val)) {
                  final newVal = val.replaceAll(trim, " ");
                  _roomIdController.text = newVal;
                  _roomIdController.selection = TextSelection.fromPosition(
                      TextPosition(offset: _roomIdController.text.length));
                }
              },
```

*Don't change the order in the above code and understanding all the statements is necessary before making any modifications.

Answer (score 0):

```
import 'package:intl/intl.dart';

var f = NumberFormat("###,###.0#", "en_US");
print(f.format(int.parse("1000300")));
```

Add this in your `TextField()` or `TextFormField()`

```
TextEditingController textController = new TextEditingController();

TextField(
      controller: textController,
      onChanged: (value) {
        var f = NumberFormat("###,###.0#", "en_US");
        controller.text = f.format(int.parse("1000300")).toString();
      },
),
```